# Make navigations items change color when active

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the html code

```
 <header>  <nav> <a href="#" id="menu-icon"></a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

the css code :

```
a {
    color: #7e7e7e;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}
a:hover {
    color: #444;
}

a.active {
  color: #82b965;
}


nav {
    float: right;
    padding: 20px;
}


ul {
    list-style: none;
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px
}
.current {
    color: #333333;
}
```

and javascript is:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {   
$("nav a").on(function(){
    $("nav a").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
});
```

what I want is that when any button will active that time the color will be green,and other will remain same color.and I want to put them in the middle,and needs to be little big space between them.
the jsfiddle is:
[jsfiddle code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVgbKE)

I have done this..But not working..

Comment: `<a href="#"">Home</a>` should be `<a href="#">Home</a>`

Comment: is this for a HTML page where you can change the html on each page or is it for tabs? - If you are trying to make tabs then maybe look at jQuery UI tabs: https://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: @salini please check my updated answer to make nav links center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {   
$("nav a").click(function(){
    $("nav a").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
});
```

Fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/130w0y9c/

To make nav links center

Updated Fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/130w0y9c/1/

Answer (score 1):

there were some small errors. just use `click()` function if you use jquery anyway.

**working fiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/94b94u1g/

Comment: do you use bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QbZdWr Done, working... the main problem was the on click

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {   
  $("nav ul li a").on("click", function(){
    $("nav ul li a").each(function () {
      $(this).removeClass("active"); 
    });
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You had two errors:

- First, as @Andrew said, `<a href="#"">Home</a>` should be `<a href="#">Home</a>`.
- Secondly, your use of the `.on` function in jQuery was missing out your target event. `$("nav a").on(function(){...` should have been `$("nav a").on("click", function(){...` . Also, if you're going by the codepen, make sure you have jQuery running it.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwPJWZ